# OleDbCommand.Prepare method requires all parameters to have an explicitly set type for password Change

Tags: vb.net, passwords

I need help with an issue involving the code for a password change function I am having on my program. Everytime I try and change the password I get the error "OleDbCommand.Prepare method requires all parameters to have an explicitly set type" if you could help me decipher what the problem is it would be much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
Dim currentpassword As String

currentpassword = txtCurrentPassword.text

sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE Code1 = @CurrentPassword"

darunnerlogin = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery, RunnerConnection)
darunnerlogin.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentPassword", txtCurrentPassword.Text)

darunnerlogin.Fill(dsrunnerlogin, "login")

    RunnerConnection.Close()
If dsrunnerlogin.Tables("Login").Rows.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox("Please Enter a Correct Password")
Else

    Dim cbRunners As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(darunnerlogin)

    dsrunnerlogin.Tables("login").Rows(0).Item(2) = txtNewPassword.Text
    darunnerlogin.Update(dsrunnerlogin, "login")
    MsgBox("Password Updated")
End If
```

Comment: What database are you using? Could you show the schema of the table tblLogin?

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301250/oledbcommand-prepare-error

Comment: Hi steve I am using an Access database

Comment: to fix your problem follow the linked answer from @the_lotus It is the correct one

Comment: You have told the `OleDbDataAdapter` how to get the data but you have not told it how to save it. `darunnerlogin.Update` doesn't know what to do. Try setting the `UpdateCommand`.